# org.omnifaces.EXCEPTION_TYPES_TO_UNWRAP doesn't work for non-ajax requests

Tags: ajax, jsf, omnifaces

I use `FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory` to handle exceptions during both ajax and non-ajax requests.

[The OmniFaces showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) says

> The `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` will transparently handle exceptions during ajax requests exactly the same way as exceptions during synchronous (non-ajax) requests.

I noticed that if an exception happened during a synchronous request, `findExceptionRootCause` (the method that actually does unwrapping) doesn't get called. Therefore, the rules defined in the `web.xml` aren't being applied since they rely on `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` unwrapping.

Does it mean I need to extend the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` or is there something I am missing?

### Stack trace :

(non-ajax request)

```
javax.servlet.ServletException:
     Caused by: javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException
          Caused by: javax.el.ELException
               Caused by: xxx.MyException
```

### web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.EXCEPTION_TYPES_TO_UNWRAP</param-name>
    <param-value>javax.servlet.ServletException,javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException,javax.el.ELException</param-value>
</context-param>
...
<error-page>
    <exception-type>xxx.MyException</exception-type>
    <location>/xxx/page-not-found.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/xxx/internal-server-error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

*I remember `ELException` may be omitted since it will be included anyway. For the sake of certainty, I included every type preceded my exception in the stack trace.

### Result:

`/xxx/internal-server-error.xhtml` is shown

### Expected:

`/xxx/page-not-found.xhtml` is shown

---

### Update:

For the exception mentioned above, if I define `<error-page>` like

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException</exception-type>
    <location>/blueglue/templates/error/page-not-found.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

or

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/blueglue/templates/error/page-not-found.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

I will get the expected outcome - the 404 page.

For `javax.el.ELException` and `xxx.MyException`, the exception results in the 500 page which isn't what I am expecting.

Comment: Have you checked the "Normal requests" section of the showcase page?

Comment: @BalusC I did, a moment ago :) The introduction misled me into thinking this handler treat both ajax and non-ajax exceptions the same. I was thinking about it like `FullExceptionHandler + Ajax =  FullAjaxExceptionHandler`, which isn't the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I use `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` to handle exceptions during both ajax and non-ajax requests.*

The `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` does **not** handle exceptions during non-ajax requests. Its sole purpose is to handle exceptions during ajax requests **the same way** as non-ajax requests (namely, showing an error page defined in `web.xml`).

Further in the showcase page which you linked you can find this section:

> #### Normal requests
>
> Note that the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` does not deal with normal (non-ajax) requests at all. To properly handle JSF and EL exceptions on normal requests as well, you need an additional `FacesExceptionFilter`. This will extract the root cause from a wrapped `FacesException` and `ELException` before delegating the `ServletException` further to the container (the container will namely use the first root cause of `ServletException` to match an error page by exception in `web.xml`).

So, all you need to do is to install the [`FacesExceptionFilter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter) in order to get the same unwrapping behavior as `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`.